# Offset Management For Apache Kafka With Apache Spark Batch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm writing a Spark (v2.2) batch job which reads from a Kafka topic. Spark jobs are scheduling with cron.
I can't use Spark Structured Streaming because non based-time windows are not supported.

```
val df = spark
        .read
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "...")
        .option("subscribe", s"kafka_topic")
```

I need to set the offset for the kafka topic to know from where to start the next batch job. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using KafkaUtils to create stream, you can pass this as parameter.

```
val inputDStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String,String](ssc,PreferConsistent,
                           Assign[String, String](fromOffsets.keys,kafkaParams,fromOffsets))
```

Hoping this helps !

Comment: down vote
accept
For batch queries, latest offset is not allowed. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

I must pass to Spark Streaming to have a new query resuming from where the last query left off.